# How to fixed error after scanning QRCode using Zbarcam

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Good Night All,
Please helpme,how to fixed my problem about Zbarcam.
I created application scanning qrcode,but after success scanning and open Scanning again,get Problem like this:

`your text`
[ERROR  ] [OpenCV      ] Couldn't get image from Camera
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\aan001\Desktop\contoh\virt\Lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 144, in _update
self._buffer = frame.imageData
^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'imageData'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\aan001\Desktop\contoh\virt\Lib\site-packages\kivy\core\camera\camera_opencv.py", line 148, in _update
self._buffer = frame.reshape(-1)
^^^^^^^^^^^^^
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'reshape'

Please,how to fixed this problem.

I want to after sucess scanning and i want to open scanning no problem.
I used Zbarcam in kivymd.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.